# "The directory name is invalid." when trying to run PowerShell startup scripts

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have a GPO startup script that creates a text file in C:\Windows\Temp:

```
Set-Content C:\Windows\Temp\GPOtest.txt -Value "$(Get-Date)"
```

**Obviously, the final script will do something more useful. This is just a test.**

The script is saved in \\*domain.tld*\NETLOGON and called from *Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts\Startup\PowerShell Scripts*. I also have *System/Group Policy/Specify startup policy processing wait time* set to 300 seconds.

After rebooting, I see Event ID 1130: Startup Script Failed in the System log. In the details, it says "The directory name is invalid."

As a test, I created a batch file in NETLOGON and added it to the same GPO. That ran as expected. I added the same PowerShell script to the shutdown scripts. That also ran as expected. My guess is something hasn't initialized yet when I run the PowerShell script at startup. What do I need to do to allow my script to run?

Comment: Such error are often because in computer GPO the context is not the user connected, but the computer account. To debug please run your powershell script as an admin, the path would be system32 by default and you will see if a bad path, which the computer account cant access get in error

Comment: @yagmoth555 The script itself is fine. I can run it as an admin or the system account with no issues. The problem is running it in the group policy context.

Comment: If connected, does a gpupdate /force give an error too? I ask as the network is ready at that state (it would point to setting "wait for network" policy settings (Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon - Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative templates\System\Logon))

Comment: Have you considered it is not the set-content command generating the error, but actually the path to the script that is invalid? Please [edit] your question and show your group policy configuration so it is clear where the file resides and how you are referencing it. If it’s on a network, have you considered the network is not online yet? That can be the case if you do not “always wait for the network at computer startup.” Or, perhaps you are referencing this script via a mapped network drive that does not exist in this context. It is likely not the set-content command with the problem.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm sorry my question isn't clear. I never thought Set-Content was generating the error. "Obviously, the final script will do something more useful. This is just a test." My intention was to remove the script contents as a possible cause of the error. The real script checks for/installs our antivirus.  
The file resides in \\domain.tld\NETLOGON. I am referencing it in _Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Scripts\Startup\PowerShell Scripts_.  
If a batch file in \\domain.tld\NETLOGON works, why would a PS script in the same location not?